# Proper Left join of three tables - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

***Update - Ok the three answers all make sense, i'm going to try them each as I am curious if there is a performance +/- but i'm not sure I have enough test data in my tables to determine that.***

I am trying to look at Table A and search to see if a user exists in Table B or Table C so as to find anyone form table A who does not exists in at least one of the other two tables (they do not need to exists in both, just B or C)

Something like this but without having to have to almost identical statements below

```
SELECT emp_id
FROM
    tableA
LEFT JOIN
    TableB
ON 
    tableA.emp_id = tableB.emp_id
WHERE 
    TableA.emp_id IS NULL

SELECT emp_id
FROM
    tableA
LEFT JOIN
    TableC
ON 
    tableA.emp_id = tableC.emp_id
WHERE 
    TableA.emp_id IS NULL



Table A
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Emp_ID  | Status | hire_date | 
+---------+--------+-----------+
| 12345   | happy  | 10/10/2005|
| 54321   | sad    | 12/01/2009|
+---------+--------+-----------+

Table B
+---------+--------+
| Emp_ID  | Weight |  
+---------+--------+
| 12345   | 185    |
| 54321   | 150    |
+---------+--------+

Table C
+---------+--------+
| Emp_ID  | City   | 
+---------+--------+
| 12345   | Chicago|
| 54321   | Atlanta|
+---------+--------+
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You can join all tables in a single query.

```
SELECT  a.Emp_ID                   -- a.* <<== if you want to include all columns
FROM    tbA a
        LEFT JOIN tbB b
            ON a.Emp_ID = b.Emp_ID
        LEFT JOIN tbC c
            ON a.Emp_ID = c.Emp_ID
WHERE   b.Emp_ID IS NULL 
        AND c.Emp_ID IS NULL              -- <<== AND should be use here
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just express the query using `not in`?

```
SELECT emp_id
FROM tableA
WHERE emp_id not in (select emp_id from TableB) and
      emp_id not in (select emp_id from TableC);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can join 3 table simply as below

```
   Select emp_id from table1 a left join table2 b on a.emp_id=b.emp_id
     left join table3 c on c.emp_id=a.emp_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query can't work because you have a WHERE tableA.emp_id IS NULL, and TableA is the emp_id you want to test for, you should have tested with `TableB.eemp_id IS NULL` and `TableC.emp_id IS NULL` for the second query.

Since you want rows that do not exists in at least tableB or tableC, you can do a LEFT JOIN with both tableB and tableC and test if at least one of the emp_id in those tables IS NULL with a **OR**

```
SELECT emp_id
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON tableA.emp_id = tableB.emp_id
LEFT JOIN TableC ON tableA.emp_id = tableC.emp_id
WHERE 
    TableB.emp_id IS NULL
 OR TableC.emp_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Agreed, I made a mistake when I copied my WHERE to the forum, it should have been tableB.emp_id but when I use the OR instead of AND like you show above I get a bunch of results, I think it is showing everyone in A who is not in B then everyone from A who is not in C.  When I use AND it works.  I was confused because I was getting a emp_id showing twice but I realized I had a duplicate and needed to SELECT DISTINCT and it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: With OR you have rows that are not in B OR not in C and right, that may give you much more results.